# How to get all combinations of two numbers in the range of 1 to 7?

Tags: java

Write a program that displays all combinations of the two numbers in the range of 1 to 7, wherein both positions cannot be displayed in the same number. Show the number of possible combinations. (For example, (1.2), (2.1) is allowed, but the combination of (1,1), (2,2) not allowed...).

Can someone give me some hint?
I'm new to Java. I have no idea what to do.
Thanks!

**I used this program as the idea for my problem.**

```
public class PossibleCombinations {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

    int[] input = { 1, 4, 3 };

    for (int x = 0; x < 3; x++) {

      for (int y = 0; y < 3; y++) {

         for (int z = 0; z < 3; z++) {

           if (x != y && y != z && z != x) {
             System.out.println(input[x] + "" + input[y] + "" + input[z]);
           }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Fortunately, it didn't go well in my case, here is my code:**

```
public class Domaci17 {
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        new Domaci17();
    }
    public Domaci17() {
      int[] unos = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
      for (int a = 0; a <= 7; a++ ) {
          for (int b = 0; b <= 7; b++ ) {
              for (int c = 0; c <= 7; c++ ) {
                  for (int d = 0; d <= 7; d++ ) {
                      for (int e = 0; e <= 7; e++ ) {
                          for (int f = 0; f <= 7; f++ ) {
                              for (int g = 0; g <= 7; g++ ) {
                                if (a != b && b != c && c != d && d != e && e != f && f != g && g != a) {
                        System.out.println(unos[a] + "" + unos[b]);
                        System.out.println(unos[b] + "" + unos[c]);
                        System.out.println(unos[c] + "" + unos[d]);
                        System.out.println(unos[d] + "" + unos[e]);
                        System.out.println(unos[e] + "" + unos[f]);
                        System.out.println(unos[f] + "" + unos[g]);
                        System.out.println(unos[g] + "" + unos[a]);
                    }  

                              }
                          }

                      }
                  }
              }
          }
      }

    }

}
```

---

```
public class Domaci17 { 
    public static void main (String[] args) {

        new Domaci17();
    }
    public Domaci17() {
      int[] unos = {1,2,3,4,5,6,7};
      for (int a = 0; a <= 7; a++ ) {
          for (int b = 0; b <= 7; b++ ) {
                                if (a != b ) {
                        System.out.println(unos[a] + "" + unos[b]);
                    }  
                 }   
              }    
    }

}
```

When I "cut" code I get 12, 13. 14, 15, 16, 17.
But how to get other combination? 
(21, 23, 24....27)
(31,......37)
(41,....47)
(51,.....57)
(61...67)
(71......76)

Comment: What have you tried so far and where are you stuck? You can't expect the community to simply complete this problem for you

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow :-) We're happy to help, but we tend to prefer more specific questions that can be answered in a more focused manner. Perhaps a Java tutorial might help? There are some over at oracle.com.

Comment: When you manually (with pen and paper) write all those combinations down, how do you proceed? What is your algorithm? Translate that into "computer".

Comment: @Michael I didn't ask anybody to write me a whole program. I ask for a hint.

Comment: The example program is pretty close to what you need. It uses *three* loops to generate combinations of *three* elements, you just have two. So your program would even be a bit simpler ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please state your problem more clearly. As far as i understood your problem you may want to do something like this -

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    for(int i=1;i<8;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<8;j++){
            if(i!=j){
                System.out.println(i+","+j);
            }
        }
    }   

}
```

Comment: I want to print all combinations of numbers from 1 to 7.
Output should be look like this:
12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17; 21, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27; .... 71, 72, 73, 74, 75, 76;

Comment: Hey! Your code work perfectly! Thanks a lot! @AritroSen

Answer (score 0):

in case duplicate combinations not allowed, for example, 2,1 - 1,2 use the following code

```
for(int i=1;i<7;i++)
{
    for(int j=i;j<7;j++)
    {   if(j!=i)
            System.out.println(i+" , "+j);
    }
    System.out.println("----------");
}
```